# Merge two rows if ID is the same in MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

How to combine the product's quantity into a single row if the Product ID is the same? This is for my customer's cart. When I add to cart a product, I want it to combine into a single row instead of a seperate row.

EDIT: I have two tables which contains a seperate quantity field (tblproducts, tblcart).

EDIT2: PHP is giving me an error

> mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result boolean
>   given on my line 61

```
              <?php 
            $query = "SELECT * FROM products";
            $exec = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            $a = 1;
            $b = 1;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)) {
```

but my code works just fine. Can anyone find the problem?

Code for my customer's cart

```
        <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Product ID</th>
          <th>Product Name</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Price per Unit</th>
          <th>Total Amount</th>
          <th>Remove</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>


      <?php 

        $selectCart = "SELECT * FROM cart INNER JOIN products ON products.product_id = cart.product_id";
        $execSelectCart = mysqli_query($connection, $selectCart);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($execSelectCart)) {

          $cartProId = $row['product_id'];
          $cartProName = $row['product_name'];
          $cartProDesc = $row['description'];
          $cartSellPrice = $row['sell_price'];
          $cartQty = $row['quantityCart'];

          $compute = $cartSellPrice * $cartQty;
          $totalAmount = number_format((float)$compute, 2, '.', '');
       ?>

        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $cartProId; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $cartProName; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $cartProDesc; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $cartQty; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $cartSellPrice; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $totalAmount ?></td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <a href="edit_brand.php?brand_id=<?php echo $brand_id; ?>"  class="btn btn-xs btn-info" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
              </a>
              <a href="manage_brands.php?delete=<?php echo $brand_id; ?>"  class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

      <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Code for adding a product

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['addCart']) && $_POST['addCart']=="Add Items to Cart") {
     foreach($_POST['qtyBuy'] as $index=>$value){
       if($value > 0){
        $cartID = $_POST['product_id'][$index];
           $addQuery = "INSERT INTO cart (product_id, quantityCart) VALUES (".$_POST['product_id'][$index].", ".$value.");";
           $addQuery .= "UPDATE products SET quantity = quantity - $value WHERE product_id = $cartID;";
           $execQuery = mysqli_multi_query($connection, $addQuery);
        }  
     }
     header('Refresh: 0; url=add_sales.php');
  }
?>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12"> <!-- Product List Info Start -->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <strong>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
          <span>Select Products</span>
       </strong>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group pull-left">
           <input type="text" class="search form-control" placeholder="Search products">
         </div>
         <span class="counter pull-left"></span>
          <div class="span3">

              <form action="add_sales.php" method="POST">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover results table-fixed">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">#</th>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>In Stock</th>
                    <th style="width: 20%">Quantity</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="warning no-result">
                  <td colspan="8"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> No Product Found</td>
                </tr>
              </thead>


              <tbody>
              <?php 
                $query = "SELECT * FROM products";
                $exec = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                $a = 1;
                $b = 1;
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)) {

                  $product_id = $row['product_id'];
                  $product_name = $row['product_name'];
                  $product_price = $row['sell_price'];
                  $description = $row['description'];
                  $product_quantity = $row['quantity'];

               ?>
              <tr>
              <td class="text-center"><?php echo $product_id; ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>">
              </td>
                  <td><?php echo $product_name; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $description; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $product_price; ?></td>
                  <td><input type="number" name="hehe" value="<?php echo $product_quantity; ?>" id="<?php echo "qtyResult" . $a++; ?>" disabled></td>
                  <td><input type="number" name="qtyBuy[]" id="<?php echo "qtyBuy" . $b++; ?>" onkeyup="updateStock(this, event)"></td>
              </tr>
              <?php } ?>
              </tbody>
          </table>


          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" name="addCart" value="Add Items to Cart" class="btn btn-info pull-right">

          </div>
          </form>
```

Table's image

[image]

Comment: Why are you insert and update the cart table at a time. First check the cart contains the product or not(using select query). If it is there then update the quantity otherwise insert the product

Comment: @balaraman Hello. Do you mind if you can create a quick snippet?

Comment: Use `GROUP BY` in your select query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, your basic problem is that you allow the database to store the same product ID multiple times under the same cart in the `cart` table. My solution relies on the presence of a field that has the same value for all items in the same cart. I use `cart_id` but it could be something else.

Since you want a product to appear only once in the same cart, you should do two things:

**1.** Add a `UNIQUE INDEX(cart_id, product_id)` the `cart` table.  Once you've done this any attempt to add the same product to the same cart will fail with an error. Run this query just once:

```
ALTER TABLE `cart` ADD UNIQUE INDEX (cart_id, product_id);
```

**2.** Change the query you use to add items to cart. As I pointed out above, a regular `INSERT` will fail if the product is already in that cart. Instead, use `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` query.  This query will insert the product id if it's not found. However if the cart already has that product, the query will update the existing record.

Change:

```
INSERT INTO cart (product_id, quantityCart) 
    VALUES (".$_POST['product_id'][$index].", ".$value.")
```

To:

```
INSERT INTO cart (cart_id, product_id, quantityCart) 
    VALUES ($cartID, {$_POST['product_id'][$index]}, $value)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantityCart = quantityCart + $value
```

I used `cart_id` in my solution as the way to determine all items that belong to the same cart. If you have another field that does this (eg: `user_id`), use that instead of `cart_id`. The basic solution is the same.

Comment: Thank you my friend. I can't upvote yet because I'm new here. I appreciate the time you've given on analyzing and correcting my code. Please edit `$_POST[product_id]` to `$_POST['product_id']`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this table

`id  employee_id contract_id      month    year    d1     d2      d3
1          25        1                11     2011    1      01      01
2          16        5                11     2011    1      11      0
3          29        3                11     2011    1      001     100
1          25        4                11     2011    0      11      011`

You want to merge this on the basis of Id, In your case its product_id

```
    id  employee_id contract_id      month    year    d1     d2      d3
    1          25        1,4            11       2011    1,0    01,11   01,011
    2          16        5              11       2011    1      11      0
    3          29        3              11       2011    1      001     100
```

You can do that by this query

```
SELECT
    id,
    employee_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(contract_id SEPARATOR ',') AS contract_ids,
    `month`,
    `year`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(d1 SEPARATOR ',') AS d1s,
    GROUP_CONCAT(d2 SEPARATOR ',') AS d2s,
    GROUP_CONCAT(d3 SEPARATOR ',') AS d3s
FROM
    `table`
WHERE
    `month` = 11 AND `year` = 2011
GROUP BY
    employee_id
```